# Newton's convergence for systems of equation analysis

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, newton-raphson, numerical-calculus

So I solved a question using Newton's Method for systems of equations. Then they asked:

> How can you ensure that Newton's method converges as it should? What
> convergence rate do you observe?

My idea was to check $|x_{n+1} - x_{n}|$ at every iteration and see that the error is decreasing quadratically.
I am using the same equations for 3 different scenarios.

**First** one it seems like it is decreasing by half until around iteration 4, and after that it kind of looks like it is decreasing quadratically.

**Second** one, decreases by half until around iteration 8 and after it doesn't seem to have any pattern.

**Third** one decreases by half until aorund iteration 10 then decreases kinda quadratically.

My question is why? Why is the second and third not decreasing quadratically from the get go? Also why is the second not behaving like Newton's method. Is it because ther might be double roots?

The print is as follows:

**First**

Iter__________x___________y_____________**$|\vec{x}_{n+1} - \vec{x}_{n}|$**

```
1   -93.2691075514873   925.137299771167    262.652751611591

2    32.2982202134813   957.6116086759      129.698629680021

3    92.0628220739525   973.067971226022    61.7309223875802

4   116.816890313347    979.469885425866    25.5685040591496

5   123.281762471589    981.141835121963    6.67757349706366

6   123.792362353483    981.273886815556    0.527399174413201

7   123.795587686334    981.274720953362    0.00333144981658602

8    123.79558781504    981.274720986648    1.32939971766592e-07

9    123.79558781504    981.274720986648    4.98866793196928e-14
```

**Second**

```
1  -811.324797843665   2089.42580862534    1257.96088578934

2  -207.971102392269   2264.39838030624    628.212609436874

3   92.2371291895562   2351.45876746497    312.577179783993

4   239.453474253177   2394.15150753342    153.281839460659

5   307.65763474734    2413.93071407673    71.0142557533089

6   333.308186188558   2421.36937399468    26.7073856941016

7   338.367321823104   2422.8365233287     5.26757824213792

8   338.580730096101   2422.89841172787    0.222200956198675

9   338.581111187739   2422.89852224444    0.000396793081132822

10  338.581111188954   2422.8985222448     1.26530035414541e-09

11  338.581111188954   2422.8985222448     1.62967534042146e-13
```

**Third**

```
1  -12738.1250000001   -6768.71250000003    15878.8624410971

2  -6030.76538636056   -2520.71807802813    7939.40360454024

3  -2677.1322400338    -396.750418688086    3969.64657092593

4  -1000.40898331252    665.174310568713    1984.71282815351

5  -162.233951488883    1196.01849739038    992.135542481428

6   256.480661911184    1461.20441921042    495.62637198429

7   465.094481230214    1593.32650477914    246.933130838899

8   567.932740426527    1658.45740227013    121.728145317798

9   616.554533055372    1689.2512042684     57.552905747243

10  636.211610445708    1701.70068661561    23.2677953885447

11  640.984825100492    1704.72372256364    5.64998446756525

12  641.303898483309    1704.92580237276    0.377682502739795

13  641.305337111327    1704.92671350384    0.00170288297146311

14  641.305337140574    1704.92671352236    3.4619367114589e-08

15  641.305337140574    1704.92671352236    3.29609026243582e-14
```

Comment: If double roots occur, the rate here is too fast then. The quadratic convergence has a constant dependency, $e_{n+1}\le M e_n^2$, where $M$ depends on $f''$ and $1/f'$, if either of them grows fast, the convergence may not look quadratic. While if this constant is uniformly bounded, then you will see the quadratic convergence after a few more iterations.